# ssh server offering rfc 2048 modulus for gex, even when moduli does not contain such group length

Tags: ssh

Regarding OpenSSH version 6.7p1

Running https://github.com/Knio/sshsec against Debian server with OpenSSH
 (OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017)

GEX groups show

- 768 GEX = EOF (server does not support 768bit group)
- 1024 GEX

  - dec: 32317006071311007300338913926423828248817941241140239112842009751400741706634354222619689417363569347117901737909704191754605873209195028853758986185622153212175412514901774520270235796078236248884246189477587641105928646099411723245426622522193230540919037680524235519125679715870117001058055877651038861847280257976054903569732561526167081339361799541336476559160368317896729073178384589680639671900977202194168647225871031411336429319536193471636533209717077448227988588565369208645296636077250268955505928362751121174096972998068410554359584866583291642136218231078990999448652468262416972035911852507045361090559
  - hex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

`/etc/ssh/moduli` does not contain any group of length 768 or 1024, however when GEX of length 1024 is requested, [RFC3526](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3526.txt) 2048-bit MODP Group is offered (page 2, paragraph 3)

Same happens, if `moduli` does not contain groups for ie. 8192 length, then again, this RFC provided 2048 moduli value is offered.

My question is, is it possible to disable offering of 1024 group at all?
If not, is the best solution to at least generate custom moduli for 1024?

Comment: Did you try with some more recent OpenSSH version?

Comment: Yes, OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017 does correctly handle moduli, does not provide 1024 group when not available in /etc/ssh/moduli, and provides default 8k group for 8192 group gex, instead of 2k group